# Stored Procedure Return nvarchar

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the same code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST1 
    (@id INT, @name NVARCHAR(30) OUTPUT)
AS
    SELECT @name = NAME 
    FROM TEACHER 
    WHERE ID = @id;
```

AND

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST2(@id INT)
AS
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(30);

    SELECT @name = NAME 
    FROM TEACHER 
    WHERE ID = @id;

    RETURN @name;
```

The top code is OK, but the second I get an error :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TEST2, Line 174
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Nguyễn Thanh Tùng' to data type int.

Can you help me explain and fix it ??

Answer (score 4):

You *cannot* return a `varchar` from a SQL Server stored procedure using `RETURN` - you can only return **integer** values.

See the MSDN documentation on ["Returning Data Using a Return Code"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) which clearly states:

> A procedure can return an **integer** value called a return code to indicate the execution status of a procedure.

Typically, such a value is used to either indicate the number of rows affected by your stored procedure, or to indicate an error code.

If you need to return a string, you have to use either an `OUTPUT` parameter, or return a result set (using a `SELECT` statement).